# Generating Facebook SDK's Key Hash for Android app in Amazon AppStore

Tags: android, facebook, amazon-appstore

I'm publishing an Android app at Amazon AppStore and doubted about integration with Facebook.

The instructions on Facebook's site are very clear in case if I'm using just my certificate to sign app. However, as I understand Amazon signs the app with its own certificate and, therefore, I should generate a new Key Hash for Facebook SDK.

So my question is: how do I generate Key Hash for Amazon Appstore signed app (if I don't have their keystore)?

Answer (score 4):

We got in touch with **Amazon** through their [Developer Portal](http://developer.amazon.com) (Help -> Contact Us -> Questions about application signature) regarding this issue.

Looks like they enabled a flag for our app that gives us an option to sign the binary ourselves. When uploading a binary, you get an option: **Amazon will sign the binary** or **I will sign the binary**.

If you want to sign the binary, the process looks like this:

**Step 1:** You upload an unsigned APK

**Step 2:** You download the processed binary that contains their injected code

**Step 3:** You sign the processed binary with your key and upload again

This way, you can reuse your existing Key Hash for Facebook SDK.

Comment: This is old. Amazon provides you the hash now.

Answer (score 4):

Amazon provides you the hash. Under the "Binary File" tab, there is a section titled "Appstore Certificate Hashes". You just need to copy the sha1 base 64 hash to the Facebook app settings.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it like this:

I run the amazon app on my kindle fire without having the key.
When the invalid parameter error was displayed I wrote the key down and entered in in my facebook app  description page.

The key was something like '-aQe9Ti2YD9.....' and but it did not work.

Then I replaced the '-' by '+' and voila, it worked.

Please make sure to replace '-' and '_' by '+' and '/' in the key string that is displayed by the facebook app! ( See http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64  section URL applications )

Comment: I took the LogCat error message:

`Invalid key hash. The key hash btQJnt+wIgqF3iJwXXXXXXX does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/XXXXXXXXXX`

and add a = after de hash. Later I put this hash in the settings section of my app in the Facebook Developer Console.

    `btQJnt+wIgqF3iJwXXXXXXX=`

Comment: As @MartinCR said. Taking the hash from the hash error message from the phone and adding an = at the end worked.

Answer (score 0):

AFIK, they double sign the apk with their key, your signature is not removed. You might want to have a look at an apk downloaded from Amazon to confirm. Since your signature/certificate is still there, presumably it should work without you having to do anything different than for  the Android Market. I haven't tried it though (can't download from Amazon).

Answer (score 0):

I got in touch with them through the contact us on the bottom and asked for the key hash for facebook connect.
They replied with the hash less than 5 min. after I sent them the questions.
Done!